# Add class to odd and even table class to float them left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looked at some answers for this question but i have tried a few and cant get it working.

How would i add a class to each to separate odd and even tables , i tried this but cant get it working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('.leaguehistorymodule:odd').addClass("column-left");
$('.leaguehistorymodule:even').addClass("column-right");
});
</script>
```

Here is the current HTML

```
<div id="mfl-singlegame">
    <div id="HPG" class="leaguehistorymodule"></div>
    <div id="LPG" class="leaguehistorymodule"></div>
    <div id="LPIW" class="leaguehistorymodule"></div>
    <div id="HPIL" class="leaguehistorymodule"></div>
    <div id="HCOMB" class="leaguehistorymodule"></div>
    <div id="LCOMB" class="leaguehistorymodule"></div>
    <div id="WINMARGIN" class="leaguehistorymodule"></div>
    <div id="LOWMARGIN" class="leaguehistorymodule"></div>
</div>
```

I want the HTML to be this after script runs

```
<div id="mfl-singlegame">
    <div id="HPG" class="leaguehistorymodule column-left"></div>
    <div id="LPG" class="leaguehistorymodule column-right"></div>
    <div id="LPIW" class="leaguehistorymodule column-left"></div>
    <div id="HPIL" class="leaguehistorymodule column-right"></div>
    <div id="HCOMB" class="leaguehistorymodule column-left"></div>
    <div id="LCOMB" class="leaguehistorymodule column-right"></div>
    <div id="WINMARGIN" class="leaguehistorymodule column-left"></div>
    <div id="LOWMARGIN" class="leaguehistorymodule column-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use :odd/:even selectors, it works on 0 based indexes so the first element will be an even element and the second will be odd one because their indexes are 0 and 1 respectively.

I would recommend using :nth-child() selector to make use of native selector support

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.leaguehistorymodule:nth-child(odd)').addClass("column-left");
    $('.leaguehistorymodule:nth-child(even)').addClass("column-right");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Side note,

- `:even` will select the elements with index 0,2,4 .. n
- `:odd` will select the elements with index 1,3,5 .. n

Try,

```
$('.leaguehistorymodule:even').addClass("column-left");
$('.leaguehistorymodule:odd').addClass("column-right");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/45WS3/)